# How to bind dropdownlist using asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, bind

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlSampleSize" runat="server"> 
 <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10">
 <asp:ListItem Text="100" Value="100">
 <asp:ListItem Text="1000" Value="1000">
<asp:DropDownList/>
```

I have bind from codebehind file but I can't see same.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of datasource to bind.  You are just showing static bound data here.

Answer (score 0):

In markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlSampleSize" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="100" Value="100" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="1000" Value="1000" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In code-behind:

```
ddlSampleSize.Items.Add(new ListItem("10", "10"));
ddlSampleSize.Items.Add(new ListItem("100", "100"));
ddlSampleSize.Items.Add(new ListItem("1000", "1000"));
```